# SQL authentication not authenticating in MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: windows-7, windows, sql

When I try to connect to the SQL Server running on localhost using Windows Authentication in SQL Server Management Studio, I am able to connect but when I try to connect using SQL authentication, it says Login failed even though I know the user with the password exist on the DB. Here is the error log -

```
            ===================================

            Cannot connect to localhost.

            ===================================

            Login failed for user 'admin'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

            ------------------------------
            For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476

            ------------------------------
            Server Name: localhost
            Error Number: 18456
            Severity: 14
            State: 1
            Line Number: 65536


            ------------------------------
            Program Location:

               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
               at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
               at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)
               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
               at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
               at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
               at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ObjectExplorer.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
               at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
```

Comment: I need to see the message from the actual log file to figure out what the issue is.  I ask because the state is masked (there is no actual state 1) in the display but shows correctly in the log file in the server folder tree.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the login is created and enabled at the [server level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx) and that the login is assigned to the [user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx) in the database. Also make sure that [mixed mode authentication](http://www.hosting.com/support/vps/windows/mixedmode/) is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use localhost, use the name of the server. What about the firewall?